# Can I edit Content Y within Content X Edit Form using Rules?

Tags: views, rules

I have created a content type VIP PAGE, and another content VIP IMAGE. Now I want to allow the user to upload 5 VIP IMAGES at the same time as creating the VIP PAGE content.

So what I did was to add 5 Image fields to the VIP PAGE content type, then I created 5 Rules, which trigger when content type of VIP PAGE is created and it takes those 5 images and creates 5 VIP IMAGES content and uses Entity Reference field to connect the IMAGES to the PAGE.

Now this all works fine, until a user decides to Edit one of their images. I want to still use a single page (VIP PAGE Edit Form) to handle images being edited. Can anyone recommend a good way to achieve this?

I can't figure out how to tell Rules which of the images it is that was edited.

Comment: how about to tell the world about your progress in solving this issue? We need to know.

Comment: hey man. well i couldn't find a good solution so i used a method thats really really unstable and crappy. it does the job though. I created Image fields on Content X and also on Content Y. I then created a Rule, which takes the images from content X when a new node is made and creates a new node of Y and uses those image fields. For editing the images on the same page, i used a View to display the images with an edit link that opens them up in a new window. not what i want but works for now till i figure something out. seems impossible

Comment: Did you try modules from my answer?

Answer (score 3):

[Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [Inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) could help you.

- **Entity Reference:**

  > Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:
  >
  > - A generic entity reference field
  > - Four widgets:
  >
  >   - Two implemented on top of the Options module (Select and Radios/Checkboxes)
  >   - Two autocomplete widgets (one with one text field per entry, one tag-style with comma-separated entries in the same text field)
  > - Two formatters:
  >
  >   - A "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.)
  >   - A "Rendered entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a configurable view mode.
  > - Integration with Views (for both forward and backward references).
  > - Integration with Entity Metadata (and as a consequence with Search API and the like).
  > - Integration with Devel generate.
  > - Integration with Feeds and Migrate (>= 2.3) for painless data import.
- **Inline Entity Form:**

  > Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.
  >   The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
  >   Existing entities can also be referenced. Supports commerce_product_reference, commerce_line_item_reference and entity reference fields. Read the [documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/inline_entity_form/tree/README?id=a0f8bf8c59b5aa35d03383ec6a0b77791a8c149f) here.

Comment: Can you explain a bit broader how you suggest the linked modules will help here?

Comment: You create entity reference field, called images. Widget - "inline entity form - multiple". Limit - 5. Checking all checkboxes you need - just read and try it's pretty clean to understand. Next, try to create vip page and find images field on creation page. Look how it works.